# Interactive Square in Java

Tags: java

I have no idea how to do this.

I already made a 15x15 grid:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
  if (inputPositionX == i)
  System.out.println("|"); //prints y-axis
  System.out.print("#");
}
System.out.print("+");
for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++)
{
  System.out.print("-"); //prints x-axis
}
System.out.println(">"); //prints 15x15 grid
```

^ sorry, not all of the code, but it works.

I need the user to put in the position of x and y and the length he/she wants of a square and it needs to print a full square using #.

Any help will be awesome!

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
Position in x:
5 ----> This is entered by the user

Position in y:
7 ----> This is entered by the user

Length of the square:
5 ----> This is entered by the user
```

In this case, the square is shifted 5 positions up and 7 positions to the right.

```
^
|
|
|
|
| #####
| #####
| #####
| #####
| #####
|
|
|
|
|
+-------------->
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the desired output?

Comment: Position in x:
5 ----> This is entered by the user
Position in y:
7 ----> This is entered by the user
Length of the square:
5 ----> This is entered by the user
In this case, the square is shifted 5 positions up and 7 positions to the right.